# Facebook Account Kit How to change button text color property

Tags: android, account-kit

I am using facebook account kit for login with phone number. I just want to change Next button text color to White. By default text color is black. I research on [Facebook Account kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/customizing) page but not found good solution. I found button property name for text color com_accountkit_button_text_color but dont know how to use it. Please Help me... Thanks in advance

```
  configurationBuilder
            = new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
            LoginType.PHONE,
            AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);
    skin = SkinManager.Skin.CONTEMPORARY;
    uiManager = new SkinManager(SkinManager.Skin.CONTEMPORARY, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorpurple));

    configurationBuilder.setUIManager(uiManager);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Facebook Account Kit -->
<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_color">#675874</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_text_color">#5A4A68</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_status_bar_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- Button -->
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_background_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_border_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_text_color">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_pressed_background_color">#917CA4</item>

    <!-- input -->
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_accent_color">#917CA4</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_border_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_text_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_background_color">#E9E5ED</item>
</style>
```

Use this on your style file.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.